# Remainder term in an integral linked to the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, riemann-zeta-function

Sorry if this is not research level, but the following problem occurs in my own research: it is trivial to show that for $k\ge2$ integral we have
$\zeta(k)=(1/(k-1)!)\int_0^\infty t^{k-1}/(e^t-1)\,dt$ (valid in fact also for
complex $k$ with $\Re(k)>1$). Now let $m\ge1$ be a fixed integer, and for $N\ge1$ consider the following expression
$$\dfrac{1}{(k-1)!N!}\sum_{0\le j\le N}(-1)^{N-j}\binom{N}{j}(j+1)^N\int_0^\infty\dfrac{t^{k-1}}{e^t-1}(1-e^{-m(j+1)t})\,dt\;,$$
which occurs as a remainder term for the computation of $\zeta(k)$.
I would like to know the asymptotic behavior of this as $N\to\infty$. It is
experimentally of the form $c(m)^{-N}$ for some $c(m)$ depending on $m$ but not on $k$, but what is the constant $c(m)$ ?